# Two users with the same profile but able to see different field

Tags: page-layout, master-detail

I have two users with the same profile but they should be able to see only their own field. In my case, I have two accounts fields. Account 1 and 2. User 1 will be able to see account field 1, same goes to user 2. I have read this idea [(I have 2 users with the same profile and I have 100 fields on an object. Now User 1 should be able to see only 50 fields and User 2 should see other 50 fields. Is it possible?)](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DMDRAA4). But the problem is, Account field 1 is a master detail. So what should I do to make both user only can see their own account field?

Comment: Have a look at permission sets.

Comment: Are two different fields on the Account Object or is it the same field on two different accounts? (so depending on the the user, that field should be shown or not?

Comment: @SergioAlcocer It is the same field on different accounts. First Account object, second materialAccount object. Originally I want to create two fields with two different account objects. And put in a different layout. but the problem is Account object is the master detail for my current object

Comment: @SanderdeJong I will try to see the permission set. Thank you